# Conditional Field is not working with content_multigroup, cck , drupal

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I have a Content_multigroup in my content type, along with that i am using a conditional field, but whenever i put my cck fields under mutigroup the conditional field stop working.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://drupal.org/node/357506), but apparently is being ignored by the developer. I wouldn't count on being able to do this.